# Sacar el total de jugadores conectados y el total de slot de un servidor

Tags: php

estoy aprendiendo poco a poco Html y CSS y tengo un pequeño inconveniente, en mi pagina estoy visualizando en un apartado una lista de servidores de un juego y en el estoy mostrando la cantidad de jugadores que están jugando actualmente y la cantidad de slot que el servidor posee para eso estoy usando "rcon_hl_net"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se muestra en la imagen donde señalo con una imagen sale 9/11 donde el 9 indica la cantidad de jugadores que estan actualmente jugando y el 11 que indica la cantidad de slot que permite dicho servidor y abajo hay un apartado donde solo se ve el simbolo /

lo que quiero colocar ahi es la suma total de la cantidad de jugadores y slot es decir como ahorita solo tengo 2 servidores y en esos 2 servidores hay 9 jugadores si sumo serian 18 y luego colocar la suma de la cantidad de slot como los 2 permiten 11 jugadores la sumatoria final serian 22 y eso es lo que quiero poner abajo la sumatoria.

```html
<?php 
require_once('rcon_hl_net.inc');
$servers=array(
  1=>array('104.221.244.101:27510', 'a23asda36h'),
  2=>array('104.231.565.445:27711', 'a12sd63h')
);
for($i = 1; $i <=sizeof($servers); $i++) {
  $split_address=explode(':', $servers[$i][0]);
  $ip=$split_address['0'];
  $port=$split_address['1'];
  $rcon=new Rcon();
  $rcon->Connect($ip, $port, $servers[$i][1]);
  $ret=$rcon->ServerInfo();
  if(!$ret) continue;
  echo '
  <tr class="fondo-sv-tr">
  <td width=23%><img class="img-sv" src="img/maps/'.$ret['map'].'.jpg"></td>
  <td width=37%>'.$ret['name'].'<p>'.$ret['ip'].'</p></td>
  <td width=13%><div class="p"><div class="p2" style="width:0%;">'.$ret['activeplayers'].'/'.$ret['maxplayers'].'</div></div></td>
  <td width=20%><a class="display_scoreboard" target="_blank" href="www.google.com"><span class="icon-display"></a><a class="connect" href=steam://connect/'.$ret['ip'].'>CONECTAR</a></td>
  </tr>';
}
?>
```

este es el codigo que uso para sacar la informacion de los servidores y este otro es donde estoy editando la pagina

```html
<div class="content_left animate__animated animate__backInLeft">
    <div id="servers_list">
        <div class="server_box">
            <div class="box_title">
                <span class="icon-paragraph-justify">
                    <p> Lista de Servidores</p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="box_info">
                <table>
                    <?php include "include/web/server_list.php"; ?>
                </table>
                <div class="community_players">
                    <div class="p">
                        <div style="width:0%;" class="p2"> <?php$ret['activeplayers']?>/<?php$ret['maxplayers']?> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

los 2 los tengo en php separados, como podria hacer para hacerlo funcionar?

Comento que en esta parte

```html
<div style="width:0%;" class="p2"> <?php$ret['activeplayers']?>/<?php$ret['maxplayers']?> </div>
```

quise hacer lo mismo que en el codigo de arriba pero no me funciono jeje

rcon_hl_net.inc

```html
<?php

// ************************************************************************
//PHPrcon - PHP script collection to remotely administrate and configure Halflife and HalflifeMod Servers through a webinterface
//Copyright (C) 2002  Henrik Beige
//
//This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
//modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
//License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
//version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
//This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
//but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
//MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
//Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
//You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
//License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
//Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
// ************************************************************************
//
// 2009 by |PJ|ShOrTy
//    fixed protocol since HL1 Update 2008
//    fixed multible packet handling
//    added special functions to communicate with amxbans plugin
//
//

class Rcon
{

  var $challenge_number;
  var $connected;
  var $server_ip;
  var $server_password;
  var $server_port;
  var $socket;


  //Constructor
  function __construct() {
  
  }
  function Rcon()
  {
    $this->challenge_number = 0;
    $this->connected = true;
    $this->server_ip = ""; 
    $this->server_port = ""; 
    $this->server_password = "";
  }


  //Open socket to gameserver
  function Connect($server_ip, $server_port, $server_password = "")
  {
    //store server data
    $this->server_ip = gethostbyname($server_ip);
    $this->server_port = $server_port;
    $this->server_password = $server_password;

    //open connection to gameserver
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://" . $this->server_ip, $this->server_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);

    if($fp)
      $this->connected = true;
    else
    {
      $this->connected = false;
      return false;
    }

    //store socket
    $this->socket = $fp;

    //return success
    return true;

  } //function Connect($server_ip, $server_port, $server_password = "")


  //Close socket to gameserver
  function Disconnect()
  {
    //close socket
    @fclose($this->socket);
    $connected = false;

  } //function Disconnect()


  //Is there an open connection
  function IsConnected()
  {
    return $this->connected;
  } //function IsConnected()

  private function get_challenge() {
    if($this->challenge_number == "")
    {
      //send request of challenge number
      $challenge = "\xff\xff\xff\xffchallenge rcon\n";
      $buffer = $this->Communicate($challenge);
      
      //If no connection is open
      if(trim($buffer) == "")
      {
      $this->connected = false;
      return false;
      }
      //get challenge number
      $this->challenge_number = trim(substr($buffer,15));
    }
  }
  //Get detailed player info via rcon
  function ServerInfo()
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;

    //get server information
    $status = $this->RconCommand("status");

    //If there is no open connection return false
    //If there is bad rcon password return "Bad rcon_password."
    if(!$status || trim($status) == "Bad rcon_password.")
      return $status;

   //format global server info
    $line = explode("\n", $status);
    $map = substr($line[3], strpos($line[3], ":") + 1);
    $players = trim(substr($line[4], strpos($line[4], ":") + 1));
    $active = explode(" ", $players);

    $result["ip"] = trim(substr($line[2], strpos($line[2], ":") + 1));
    $result["name"] = trim(substr($line[0], strpos($line[0], ":") + 1));
    $result["map"] = trim(substr($map, 0, strpos($map, "at:")));
    $result["mod"] = "Counterstrike " . trim(substr($line[1], strpos($line[1], ":") + 1));
    $result["game"] = "Halflife";
    $result["activeplayers"] = $active[0];
    $result["maxplayers"] = substr($active[2], 1);

    //format player info
    for($i = 1; $i <= $result["activeplayers"]; $i++)
    {
      //get possible player line
      $tmp = $line[$i + 6];

      //break if no more players are left
      if(substr_count($tmp, "#") <= 0)
        break;

      //name
      $begin = strpos($tmp, "\"") + 1;
      $end = strrpos($tmp, "\"");
      $result[$i]["name"] = substr($tmp, $begin, $end - $begin);
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end + 1));

      //ID
      $end = strpos($tmp, " ");
      $result[$i]["id"] = substr($tmp, 0, $end);
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end));

      //WonID
      $end = strpos($tmp, " ");
      $result[$i]["wonid"] = substr($tmp, 0, $end);
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end));

      //Frag
      $end = strpos($tmp, " ");
      $result[$i]["frag"] = substr($tmp, 0, $end);
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end));

      //Time
      $end = strpos($tmp, " ");
      $result[$i]["time"] = substr($tmp, 0, $end);
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end));

      //Ping
      $end = strpos($tmp, " ");
      $result[$i]["ping"] = substr($tmp, 0, $end);
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end));

      //Loss
      $tmp = trim(substr($tmp, $end));

      //Adress
      $result[$i]["adress"] = $tmp;

    } //for($i = 1; $i < $result["activeplayers"]; $i++)

    //return formatted result
    return $result;

  } //function ServerInfo()


  //Get all maps in all directories
  function ServerMaps($pagenumber = 0)
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;

    //Get list of maps
    $maps = $this->RconCommand("maps *", $pagenumber);

    //If there is no open connection return false
    //If there is bad rcon password return "Bad rcon_password."
    if(!$maps || trim($maps) == "Bad rcon_password.")
      return $maps;

    //Split Maplist in rows
    $line = explode("\n", $maps);
    $count = sizeof($line) - 4;

    //format maps
    for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
      $text = $line[$i];

      //at directory output sorted map list
      if(strstr($text, "Dir:"))
      {
        //reset counter
        $mapcount = 0;

        //parse directory name
        $directory = strstr($text, " ");

      } //if(strstr($text, "Dir:"))

      else if(strstr($text, "(fs)"))
      {
        //parse mappath
        $mappath = strstr($text, " ");

        //parse mapname
        //if no "/" is included in the "maps * " result
        if(!($tmpmap = strrchr($mappath, "/")))
          $tmpmap = $mappath;

        //parse mapname without suffix (.bsp)
        $result[$directory][$i] = substr($tmpmap, 1, strpos($tmpmap, ".") - 1);

      } //else if(strstr($text, "(fs)"))

    } //for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)


    //return formatted result
    return $result;

  } //function ServerMaps()

  //Get server info via info protocoll
  function Info()
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;
  
    //send info command
    $command = "\xff\xff\xff\xffTSource Engine Query\x00";
    $buffer = $this->Communicate($command);

    //If no connection is open
    if(trim($buffer) == "")
    {
      $this->connected = false;
      return false;
    }

    //build info array
  $pos=0;
    $result["type"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"bytestr");
  
  if ($result["type"] == 'I')
  {
    $result["version"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["name"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result["map"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result["mod"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result["game"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result["appid"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"short");
    $result["activeplayers"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["maxplayers"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["botplayers"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["dedicated"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"bytestr");
    $result["os"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"bytestr");
    $result["password"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["secure"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["sversion"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result["edf"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    switch ($result["edf"]) {
      case '\x80': // The server's game port # is included 
        $result["port"]= $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"short");
        break;
      case '\x40': // The spectator port # and then the spectator server name are included 
        $result["specport"]= $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"short");
        $result["specservername"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
        break;
      case '\x20': // The game tag data string for the server is included [future use] 
        $result["gametagdata"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    }
  }
  else
  { 
    $result['adress'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result['name'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result['map'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result['mod'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result['game'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result['activeplayers'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result['maxplayers'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result['protocol'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result['dedicated'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"bytestr");
    $result['os'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"bytestr");
    $result['password'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result['modrunning'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result['modurl'] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["secure"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result["botplayers"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
  }
  $this->Communicate("");
    //return formatted result
    return $result;

  } //function Info()

  function parse_buffer($buffer,&$pos,$type) {
    $result = '';
    switch ($type) {
      case 'string':
          while ( substr($buffer, $pos,1) !== "\x00" )
          {
            $result .= substr($buffer, $pos,1);
            $pos++;
          }
          break;
      case 'short':
          $result = ord(substr($buffer, $pos,1)) +
              (ord(substr($buffer, $pos+1,1)) << 8);
          $pos++;
          break;
      case 'long':    
           $result = ord($buffer[$pos]) +
                            (ord($buffer[$pos + 1]) << 8) +
                            (ord($buffer[$pos + 2]) << 16) +
                            (ord($buffer[$pos + 3]) << 24);
          $pos+=3;
          break;
      case 'byte':
          $result = ord(substr($buffer, $pos,1));
          break;
      case 'bytestr':
          $result = substr($buffer, $pos,1);
          break;
      case 'float':
          $tmptime = @unpack('ftime', substr($buffer, $pos, 4));
          $result = date('H:i:s', round($tmptime['time'], 0) + 82800);
          $pos+=3;
          break;
    }
    $pos++;
    return $result;
  }

  //Get players via info protocoll
  function Players()
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;
  //get challenge number
    if($this->challenge_number == "")
    {
      //send request of challenge number
      $challenge = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\x55\xff\xff\xff\xff";
      $buffer = $this->Communicate($challenge);

      //If no connection is open
      if(trim($buffer) == "")
      {
        $this->connected = false;
        return false;
      }

      //get challenge number
      $this->challenge_number = substr($buffer,1,4);
    }
    //send players command
    $command = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\x55$this->challenge_number";
    $buffer = $this->Communicate($command);
  
    //If no connection is open
    if(trim($buffer) == "")
    {
      $this->connected = false;
      return false;
    }
    //get number of online players
    #$buffer = substr($buffer, 1);
  $pos=0;
  $header = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"bytestr");
  $numpl = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
  
  //build players array
  if($header!='D') return;
  $result=array();
  for($i = 0; $i < $numpl; $i++)
  {
    $result[$i]["index"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"byte");
    $result[$i]["name"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"string");
    $result[$i]["frag"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"long");
    $result[$i]["time"] = $this->parse_buffer($buffer,$pos,"float");
  } 
  
    //return formatted result
    return $result;

  } //function Players()


  //Get server rules via info protocoll
  function ServerRules()
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;
  
  
  $this->Communicate("");
  
  
  if($this->challenge_number == "")
    {
      //send request of challenge number
      $challenge = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\x56\xff\xff\xff\xff";
      $buffer = $this->Communicate($challenge);

      //If no connection is open
      if(trim($buffer) == "")
      {
        $this->connected = false;
        return false;
      }

      //get challenge number
      $this->challenge_number = substr($buffer,1,4);
    }
    //build info command
    $command = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\x56$this->challenge_number\x00";
    $buffer = $this->Communicate($command);

    //If no connection is open
    if(trim($buffer) == "")
    {
      $this->connected = false;
      return false;
    }

    //seperate rules
    $buffer = substr($buffer, 2);
    $buffer = explode("\x00", $buffer);
    $buffer_count = floor(sizeof($buffer) / 2);

    //build rules array
    for($i = 0; $i < $buffer_count; $i++)
    {
      $result[$buffer[2 * $i]] = $buffer[2 * $i + 1];
    
    }
    //sort rules
    #asort($result);

    //return formatted result
    return $result;

  } //function ServerRules()


  //Execute rcon command on open socket $fp
  function RconCommand($command, $pagenumber = 0, $single = true)
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;

    //get challenge number
  $this->get_challenge();
    
    $command = "\xff\xff\xff\xffrcon $this->challenge_number \"$this->server_password\" $command\n";

    //get specified page
    $result = "";
    $buffer = "";
    while($pagenumber >= 0)
    {
      //send rcon command
      $buffer .= substr($this->Communicate($command),1);

      //get only one package
      if($single == true)
        $result = $buffer;

      //get more then one package and put them together
      else
        $result .= $buffer;

      //clear command for higher iterations
      $command = "";

      $pagenumber--;

    } //while($pagenumber >= 0)
  
  //to get more than 1 page from rcon
  
  //write command on socket
    // // // // if($command != "")
      // // // // fputs($this->socket, $command, strlen($command));

    // // // // //get results from server
    // // // // $buffer = fread ($this->socket, 1);
    // // // // $status = socket_get_status($this->socket);

    // // // // // Sander's fix:
    // // // // while ($status["unread_bytes"] > 0 && $timeout < 10) {
    // // // // //get results from server
      // // // // $buffer .= fread($this->socket, $status["unread_bytes"]);
    // // // // $result .= substr($buffer,5);
    // // // // //echo "######".substr($buffer,20)."#########<br>";
    // // // // $buffer = fread ($this->socket, 1);
    // // // // $status = socket_get_status($this->socket);
    // // // // //echo $status["unread_bytes"];
    // // // // $timeout++;
    // // // // //echo $timeout;

    // // // // }
  //echo $buffer;

    //return unformatted result
    return trim($result);

  } //function RconCommand ($command)

  //AMXBans function to get the online players with more infos
  function ServerPlayers()
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;

    //get challenge number
  $this->get_challenge();
  
    //get specified page
    $result = "";
    $buffer = "";
  
  //write command on socket
  $command="\xff\xff\xff\xffrcon $this->challenge_number \"$this->server_password\" amx_list\n";
    fputs($this->socket, $command, strlen($command));
  
    //get first results from server
    $buffer = fread ($this->socket, 1);
    $status = socket_get_status($this->socket);
  
  $max=0;
  //try to get more results
    while ($status["unread_bytes"] > 0 && $max <= 2) {
    //get results from server
    $end="\xfb\xfb\xfb\xfb";
      $buffer .= fread($this->socket, $status["unread_bytes"]);
    $result .= substr($buffer,5);
    
    //search for the last packet from plugin
    if(stristr($buffer,$end)!==false) {
      $result=str_replace($end,"",$result);
      break;
    }
    
    //get new socket status
    $buffer = fread ($this->socket, 1);
    $status = socket_get_status($this->socket);
    $max++;
    }
  
    //return unformatted result
    return trim($result);

  } //function RconCommand ($command)

  //Communication between PHPrcon and the Gameserver
  function Communicate($command)
  {
    //If there is no open connection return false
    if(!$this->connected)
      return $this->connected;


    //write command on socket
    if($command != "")
      fputs($this->socket, $command, strlen($command));

    //get results from server
    $buffer = fread ($this->socket, 1);
    $status = socket_get_status($this->socket);

    // Sander's fix:
    if ($status["unread_bytes"] > 0) {
      $buffer .= fread($this->socket, $status["unread_bytes"]);
    }
  
    //If there is another package waiting
    if(substr($buffer, 0, 4) == "\xfe\xff\xff\xff")
    {
    //get requestid from split packages
    $requestid=substr($buffer,4,4);
    
    //get number of packages
    $po=ord(substr($buffer,8,1));
    $panum=($po & 1) + ($po & 2) + ($po & 4) + ($po & 8);
    
    //get number from current package
    $po=$po >> 4;
    $pacur=($po & 1) + ($po & 2) + ($po & 4) + ($po & 8);
    
    //add the first package to the array
    if($pacur==($panum-1)) {
      $splitbuffer[$pacur]=substr($buffer,9);
    } else {
      $splitbuffer[$pacur]=substr($buffer,14);
    }
        
    //get all missing packages, the fist one we have, so start with 1
    for ($i=1;$i<$panum;$i++) {
      //get next package
      $buffer2 = fread ($this->socket, 1);
      $status = socket_get_status($this->socket);
      $buffer2 .= fread($this->socket, $status["unread_bytes"]);
      
      //get number from current package
      $requestid2=substr($buffer,4,4);
      $po=ord(substr($buffer2,8,1));
      $po=$po >> 4;
      $pacur=($po & 1) + ($po & 2) + ($po & 4) + ($po & 8);
      
      //check the requestid from every package and add to array
      if($requestid==$requestid2) {
        if($pacur==($panum-1)) {
          $splitbuffer[$pacur]=substr($buffer2,9);
        } else {
          $splitbuffer[$pacur]=substr($buffer2,14);
        }
      }
    }
    //add to main packet, the array is ordered by package num
    for($i=0;$i<$panum;$i++) $bufferret.=$splitbuffer[$i];
    }

    //In case there is only one package
    else
      $bufferret = substr($buffer, 4);

    //return complete package including the type byte
    return $bufferret;

  } //function Communicate($buffer)

}

?>
```

Comment: ayuda por favor

Comment: Inicializa un par de variables antes del `for` e increméntalas dentro del ciclo. Al hacer el include tendrás dichas variables disponibles para el div, úsalas en lugar de `$ret`, que por cierto sólo trae los datos del último servidor consultado.

Comment: me podrias ayudar? ahi deje el inc, me estoy perdiendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q hace wachinaso!!! Para poder sumar la cantidad total de jugadores y slot que hay en los servidores, primero tnes q crear dos variables, una para almacenar la suma total de jugadores y otra para almacenar la suma total de slots. Luego, dentro del bucle for que estás utilizando para recorrer los servidores, tnes q sumar el número de jugadores y de slots de cada servidor a las variables que creaste.

Por ejemplo:

```
$total_players = 0;
$total_slots = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <=sizeof($servers); $i++) {
  // Código para obtener la información del servidor
  
  $total_players += $ret['activeplayers'];
  $total_slots += $ret['maxplayers'];
}
```

Una vez que hayas terminado de recorrer todos los servidores, puedes imprimir la suma total de jugadores y slots en la página HTML. Por ejemplo, podrías utilizar el siguiente código:

```
<div class="community_players">
  <div class="p">
    <div style="width:0%;" class="p2"> Total: <?php echo $total_players; ?>/<?php echo $total_slots; ?> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Listo, me funciono gracias